# Return results with several LIKE and NOT LIKE requirements

Tags: query, ms-access, like

I am trying to create a query that selects only a set of values, but excludes other ones.

The column I am selecting it's called "Participants" and the values therein are not a single text item, but a list of items separated by commas (length and number of items vary), for example: "Alpha, Delta, Eta" or the value: "Beta, Gamma or the value: "Delta, Beta, Epsilon, Theta, Vau".

I wrote this query to try and obtain results that will only include value like Delta, Eta, Epsilon and Vau but not Alpha, Beta, Gamma (it means that I don't want the value: "Alpha, Delta, Eta" to be included, but I want values like: "Delta, Zeta, Epsilon")

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Category, CODE, Participants
WHERE(Participants NOT LIKE '%Alpha%'
      OR Participants NOT LIKE '%Beta%'
      OR Participants NOT LIKE '%Gamma%')
     AND (Participants LIKE '%Delta%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Eta%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Epsilon%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Vau%');
```

The results include all the values specified in the LIKE part of the query, but NOT LIKE doesn't seem to work as I keep getting results like: "Alpha, Eta, Epsilon.

I could create multiple queries in Access to filter with the LIKE query and then with the NOT LIKE, but I would like to find a way to do it in a single query.

Online I could only find examples where there is a single LIKE and a NOT LIKE in the query

Can anybody suggest a solution please?

Comment: The condition `Participants NOT LIKE'%Alpha%' OR Participants NOT LIKE'%Beta%' OR Participants NOT LIKE'%Gamma%'` looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query when evaluating NOT LIKE you should use AND instead of OR, because you want all of them to be met.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name,
    Category,
    CODE,
    Participants
WHERE (Participants NOT LIKE '%Alpha%'
      AND Participants NOT LIKE '%Beta%'
      AND Participants NOT LIKE '%Gamma%')
     AND (Participants LIKE '%Delta%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Eta%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Epsilon%'
          OR Participants LIKE '%Vau%');
```

This is in contrast to those later conditions where you want any of the values be LIKE values selected where AND is used.

Alternatively you can rephrase as:

```
WHERE NOT
      (Participants LIKE '%Alpha%'
    OR Participants LIKE '%Beta%'
    OR Participants LIKE '%Gamma%'
      )
  AND (Participants LIKE '%Delta%'
    OR Participants LIKE '%Eta%'
    OR Participants LIKE '%Epsilon%'
    OR Participants LIKE '%Vau%'
      );
```

Comment: thank you, your solution did work for me. I didn't realise I had to use the AND with the multiple NOT LIKE.

Comment: @Geo_explorer: That's one of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for you. When you want either, you say, `A or B`. The opposite – neither – would be `not (A or B) → (not A) and (not B)`.  It actually makes sense on its own, without fancy names, though perhaps not immediately obvious. "I do **not** want either this **or** that = I do **not** want this **and** I do **not** want that"

Answer (score 0):

If you can put these conditions into table variables or Table Valued Parameters, the query becomes somewhat simpler:

```sql
DECLARE @ExclFilters TABLE (Value varchar(100);
INSERT @ExclFilters (Value)
VALUES
  ('Alpha'),
  ('Beta'),
  ('Gamma');
DECLARE @InclFilters TABLE (Value varchar(100);
INSERT @InclFilters (Value)
VALUES
  ('Delta'),
  ('Eta'),
  ('Epsilon'),
  ('Vau');


SELECT DISTINCT
    Name,
    Category,
    CODE,
    Participants
FROM whatever t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @ExclFilters f
    WHERE t.Participants LIKE '%' + Value + '%')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @InclFilters f
    WHERE t.Participants LIKE '%' + Value + '%');
```